# how to : systemd-resolve writes a bad resolv.conf doesn't read settings

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns

**This problem is a blocking issue, it does prevent me from using my laptop and accessing internet.**

Using Ubuntu 20.04.3  latest update Oct 19th

After the one but last update oct 10th suddenly I had a problem resolving DNS.
Before the update my /etc/resolv.conf read :

> nameserver 127.0.0.53

In my netmanager settings I had/have entered 2 DNS-Server IP adresses of my ISP :   1xx.2xx.xxx.21 1xx.2xx.xxx.22

the result of command

> $  ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 okt 13 14:10 /etc/resolv.conf ->
> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

So I did

> $ sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
>
> $ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

Only to find it didn't change anything : the content of new /etc/resolv.conf  after restarting the systemd-resolve service still reads

> nameserver ::1

I managed to complete the updates by repeatedly saving manually an /etc/resolv.conf file and overwriting the file written by the systemd-resolve service (workaround).  to make certain that people don't doubt my capacity to read :  I DO understand the warning at the top of the file saying that the file is overwritten regularly.

I manage to maintain a "usable connection" by regularly overwriting the file  /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf,

> nameserver 1xx.2xx.xxx.21
>
> nameserver 1xx.2xx.xxx.22

until i restart the systemd-resolve service and the file is overwritten by resolve and it reverts to

> nameserver ::1

I also checked the /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf file which has the following content

> nameserver 127.0.0.53
> options edns0 trust-ad

My question is :

A-  How can I make sure that the resolve service writes the correct file content in /etc/resolv.conf  = I do understand that this is a sym-link

B- Where is the parameter file that systemd-resolve uses to produce /etc/resolv.conf and /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, because it sure doesn't read the configuration entered in netmanager settings

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` is managed (part of "`systemd` takes over the world") and shouldn't be edited by the user. Let your `/etc/resolv.conf` remain as `nameserver 127.0.0.53` and read `systemd-dnsmasq dnsmasq`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @waltinator  you misread *before* the update my /etc/resolv.conf   was  nameserver 127.0.053   after the update  after the update  it read nameserver ::1
Please explain what you mean by   " read   systemd-dnsmasq dnsmasq  "

Comment: @chili555  the result of conmmand     ls -al /etc/resolv.conf     is 

nameserver ::1

Comment: I think you misread or mis-typed the command. Please try again.

Comment: @chili555  

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 okt 13 14:10 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

content of  /etc/resolv.conf  ===
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.

nameserver ::1

=== end of content 


I cut all the comment lines  the only active line in /etc/resolve.conf

Comment: Are there any interesting clues or errors if you do: `sudo service systemd-resolved restart` What is the result of: `systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2`

Comment: @chili555   no error or return from restart
the status  command returns    >    DNS Servers:  : : 1    >    DNS Domain: ~.

Comment: Read the results of typing `man systemd-resolve systemd`. Sorry for my mindo (like a typo, but in the mind, not the fingers).

Comment: @waltinator  the   man systemd-resolve systemd  doesn provide any indactaion on how I tell the  systemd-resolve  service the IP adresses of the DNS  servers of my ISP

Comment: Read `man systemd-dnsmasq systemd-dnsmasq.conf dnsmasq.conf`. `dnsmasq` is a forwarding DNS resolver, running on the localhost at `127.0.0.53`. All of the `127.*.*.*` IP addresses belong to localhost.

Comment: @waltinator  I've read  DSMASQ man pages, I could do option -2  no DHCP and put my DNS servers in a dnsmasq  config  file , however according to the man pages  in need to put << nameserver 127.0.0.1 >> in resolv.conf , which gets overwritten   with <<nameserver ::1 >> which doesn't work

Comment: @chili555  no error or return from restart of the resolve service;   the status you asked for returns 2 lines with follwing content <<  DNS Servers: : : 1  ;   DNS Domain: ~.   >>

Comment: @chili555  and what is the solution you propose? ,  what did you learn form the command?

Comment: @waltinator , now that I read the manual for resolve and dnsmasq , what  solution should i find there ? what is your solution ?

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for the comments without providing an answer or solution  you have not been of tangible help

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for the comments without providing an answer or solution  you have not been of tangible help

Comment: Correct. I regret that I am unable to solve every question ever posted but I am not. Sorry.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 address of `localhost`. Have you mistakenly enabled IPv6?